# IIS as reverse proxy to golang socket.io

Tags: go, iis, websocket, socket.io

I use IIS httpPlatformHandler to run a golang implementation of socket.io behind IIS.

When I disable IIS websocket module to let socket.io handle websocket connections I get an error reporting Sec-WebSocket-Accept response header is not present.

When I run the app as a standalone process the header is present and everything works fine. I enabled iis websocket module and the Sec-WebSocket-Accept is present now but the connection is not stable and the client gets disconnected with reason transport close.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but the problem is solved by using wss instead of ws